# Tomcat conf folder location change?

Tags: tomcat, path, config

is there a way to change tomcat's conf folder location to something other than next to bin?

right now its like this:

```
tomcat-
       bin
       conf
       webapps
       logs
       work
       temp
```

i want it to be like this:

```
tomcat-
       bin
       webapps
       logs
       work
       temp

/var/tomcat_conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have only one possibility to do something like that without patching tomcat:

Use symbolic links to redirect the conf directory to your chosen directory:

```
mv conf /var/tomcat_conf
ln -s /var/tomcat_conf conf
```

Here is a listing of `/usr/share/tomcat6` from my fedora core system:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 May 16 09:51 bin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   12 May 16 09:51 conf -> /etc/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   23 May 16 09:51 lib -> /usr/share/java/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   16 May 16 09:51 logs -> /var/log/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   23 May 16 09:51 temp -> /var/cache/tomcat6/temp
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   24 May 16 09:51 webapps -> /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   23 May 16 09:51 work -> /var/cache/tomcat6/work
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question was posted a long time ago it now has a lot more relevance in the container world (Docker, rkt etc.,).

Containers are meant to be seen as "disposable" so if you run tomcat in a container then all your config changes and logs will get lost if the container is destroyed.

One way to avoid that is to provide the container with some mount points to directories on the host file system or specific container provider managed 'volumes' outside of the container - these persist through container destruction and container upgrade cycles so you don't lose the data in them.

Under the hood I presume they are implemented as symbolic links but you don't need to worry about the underlying details.

For example this tomcat image from "dordoka" is launched like this with docker:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 8009:8009 -v /opt/tomcat/webapps:/opt/tomcat/webapps dordoka/tomcat
```

The /opt/tomcat/webapps is a directory on the container host filesystem and will be accessed by tomcat whenever it reads /opt/tomcat/webapps